# Can we determine function "k", if we know k(l-1)=f(l) holds for all function f of type int->int and l of type int?

Tags: functional-programming, f#, ocaml, tail-recursion, continuation-passing

Suppose both k and f are functions of type int -> int. If we know k(l-1)=f(l) holds for all l of type int, can we be certain that k is the function  v->f(v+1) ?

I have this question while doing an exercise of functional programming: to transform a length function

```
let rec len xs = 
  match xs with 
    | [] -> 0 
    | x:xr -> 1 + len xr;;
```

to a continuation-passing version. My answer to the exercise would be

```
   let rec lenc xs k = 
      match xs with 
        | [] -> k 0 
        | x:xr -> lenc xr (fun v -> k(v+1))
```

but I am unsure if the `(fun v -> k(v+1))` part can be replaced by other solutions. To know this, we would need to determine a unique "k", given that k(l-1)=f(l) holds for all function f of type int->int and l of type int?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want mathematical proof?

```
(1) k(i - 1) = f(i)

(2) j = i - 1
```

from (1) & (2):

```
(3) k(j) = f(i)
```

from (2):

```
(4) i = j + 1
```

from (3) & (4)

```
(5) k(j) = f(j + 1)
```

q.e.d.

Of course `(fun v -> k(v+1))` is your `k` and the inside `k` is `f`